# Cooking time for multi meats cooked together

Tags: kitchen-safety

If I cook 3 Pork Butts in the same pot at the same time how long do I cook them. Each pork butt is 2 pounds and I have three so that is 6 pounds. They say 45 mins per pound. Do I cook them for 1 hour and 50 mins or do i cook them for 4 hours and 50 mins. I am cooking them on top of the stove.